# By using Spring Integration, reading message from activemq, then calls the job?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch

I want to consume the message from activemq using spring integration . then call the job depending on what message I received from activemq .

Can anyone please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

See the [Spring Batch Integration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/springBatchIntegration.html) sub-project of Spring Batch and [Spring Integration JMS Support](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jms.html).

You wire a message-driven channel adapter to a job launching gateway with a transformer to convert the message to a job launch request.

Comment: Can u please help me , getting messages from activemq , with that I should launch the batch job

Comment: See the test cases [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-integration/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/integration/launch/JobLaunchingGatewayIntegrationTests.java) and [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-integration/src/test/resources/org/springframework/batch/integration/launch/JobLaunchingGatewayIntegrationTests-context.xml) as well as the documentation I pointed you to.